# How to distribute a larger array over a smaller array

Tags: python, algorithm, round-robin

My problem involves a bit more complexity, but the issue can be written rather generically with an example: I have a list of pools (`pools`) that need to have a list of children (`children`) distributed evenly amongst the list of `pools`.

The `children` list is already sorted, so it's safe to assume it can be distributed over the `pools` in the current order.

For example, if I had `[pool1, pool2]` and `[child1, child2, child3]` I would expect `pool1` to be assigned `child1` and `child3` and `pool2` would be assigned `child2`:

```py
pools = ['pool1', 'pool2']
children = ['child1', 'child2', 'child3']

def print_assignment(pool, child)
  print('{} assigned to {}'.format(child, pool)

# The expectation is that distribute would perform the core logic and 
# call print_assignment during each assignment
distribute(pools, children, print_assignment)
```

With the expected output being:

```
child1 assigned to pool1
child2 assigned to pool2
child3 assigned to pool1
```

The expectation is that the count of `pools` and `children` can be any size, however, the following is always true: `len(pools) < len(children)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for the task:

```
from itertools import cycle

pools = ['pool1', 'pool2']
children = ['child1', 'child2', 'child3']

c = cycle(pools)
for child in children:
    print('{} assigned to {}'.format(child, next(c)))
```

Prints:

```
child1 assigned to pool1
child2 assigned to pool2
child3 assigned to pool1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification of [Andrej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292324/how-to-distribute-a-larger-array-over-a-smaller-array/62292378#62292378) which I think is a little more readable:

```py
from itertools import cycle

pools = ['pool1', 'pool2']
children = ['child1', 'child2', 'child3']

for child, pool in zip(children, cycle(pools)):
    print(f'{child} assigned to {pool}')
```

Outputs:

```py
child1 assigned to pool1
child2 assigned to pool2
child3 assigned to pool1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so :

```
for elem in children:
    if children.index(elem) % 2 == 0:
        print(f"{elem} to {pools[0]}")
    else:
        print(f"{elem} to {pools[1]}")
```

Considering you only have two pools you can assign the children to the pool1 if his index is an odd number.

Comment: This will only work for exactly two pools. Andrej Kesely's answer works for any amount of pools.

Comment: That's why I specified that it works for two pools.